# Reducing size of node_modules for production

Tags: javascript, node.js

Our deployment process is taking ages and part of that reason is passing the `node_modules` folder to the production server.

My `Package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "coms-sass",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Sass gulp task for COMS Service Portal",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.5",
    "angular-sanitize": "=1.5.5",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^1.3.2",
    "gridster": "^0.5.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "jquery.cookie": "^1.4.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.1",
    "jshint-visual-studio": "^1.0.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.6",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ng-csv": "^0.3.6",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.0",
    "bootstrap":  "=3.3.5" 
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.6",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.6"
  }
}
```

I obviously do not want to deploy karma and phantom as part of the production build.

How can I exclude them for deployment and is there anything else I can do to reduce the size of my node_modules folder.

Comment: That's a front-end application, you don't need the `node_modules` folder on the server. And if you really need those packages, you can deploy the `package.json` file and install the dependencies on your server.

Comment: @Vohuman Most of the case I agree with you and I do feel like it is the case here. However it may not always be true. It depends how he is building his app. One may choose not to embed some libraries, and use the `node_module` dist instead if it is browser compatible.

Comment: How can I exclude karma and phantom for production?

Answer (score 4):

there is flag --production to npm install. In an production env you could install `npm i --production` this will skip all devDependencies. https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html#production

Another prossibility is 'tree shaking' with rollup.js or babel. Check this here: http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about building/compiling/transpiling the distribution files and only deploying those? I.e. transfer only whats under `'dist'` or similar directory.

Looks like you're building a browser facing parts of an application. For such app, the `node_modules` directory contains mostly build and testing tools that are to be used during compiling - you shouldn't need to transfer those anywhere. What you need though, is angular and jquery and similar, but those npm packages contain a lot of fluff and shouldn't be deployed as is either.

You should create a set of files that are needed by the user's browser only and transfer those to the production server. This is usually what's created in a `'dist'` directory during the build.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[node-prune](https://github.com/tj/node-prune):**

> `node-prune` is a small tool to prune unnecessary files from `./node_modules`, such as markdown, typescript source files, and so on.

This could be combined with other provided solutions and be made part of your build process.